# What is the extra crosshair detail that occsionally appears on medic guns?

Tags: killing-floor-2

In Killing Floor 2 I generally play as a medic, and while using medic guns I regularly see a blue highlight appear around my red dot sight. It lasts a short time and then disappears with no noticeable changes to the gun.

Normal crosshair on the left, extra detail surrounding the red dot on the right

[image]
[image]

This doesn't seem to correspond to wether I'm killing, the ammo capacity shown next to it or any other reported data. But it also doesn't seem to alter how the weapon functions? Maybe it's to do with the medic darts? But I can shoot them both with it visible and without.

Is it purely graphical, or does it mean something I've missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a blue highlight appears it is "locked on" to a player. This means that you can shoot your healing darts which will home in to the player target. Not to mention that when your aim "locks on" a little audio cue will play letting you know it is locked on.

Answer (score 0):

The extra detail appears when you aim at (or near) a player who is less than 100% health.

When you're aiming directly at them the reticule circle will expand slightly.